# Windows 10 mobile app development - Share information between devices

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile

I am new in universal app development however I am looking into a way of sharing information between devices.

I have two windows mobile phones (Both win10 phones)
I would like them to request each others location.

I've already written a small application which will get geoposition location of the phone so all I have to do now is share/send it to a different device when it requests it.

What would be the best practice to do this?
Would you recommend to record location information into a database every ~30 seconds and then query DB from the other phone to find the location on specific phone or would you recommend some other way?

By the way, I'm coding in C#

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to achieve your need:
- Send information directly using: Wifi direct, NFC, Bluetooth...
- Send over remote server: Azure (or AWS, GCS)